# JDT ASTParser: Cannot resolve to a type/variable

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I'm new here and I'm currently working on a standalone source code parser with eclipse-jdt. I have currently an issue that I can't get any further with. The source code parser should write (in this case) a compiler message in a log file:

The following code is from a visitor:

```
for (IProblem problem : problems) {
    if (problem.isError()) {
        final String msg = "Problem count: " + problems.length + " in " + resource.getAbsolutePath()
                + "\n\tERROR: " + problem.getSourceLineNumber() + " > " + problem.getMessage();
        logger.log(Level.INFO, msg);
        continue; // do not count errors
    }
    // ... 
    logCompilerMessage(getFullQualifiedName(), mainAuthor, problem);
}
```

For an example, while parsing the method readData:

```
package testproj.pckg.billing;
//...
public class Bill {
    private boolean readData(MODETYPE modeType) { 
        // MODETYPE is an enum in other class but in the same package
    }
}
```

The program will "classified" the enum MODETYPE as a error which is in class Bill2.java:

```
package testproj.pckg.billing;
// ...
public class Bill2 {
    // ...
}

enum MODETYPE { 
    // ...
}
```

The output will be looking like this:

> Problem count: 8 in E:\ws\preview\project\src\testproj\pckg\billing\Bill.java
> ERROR: 1925 > MODETYPE cannot be resolved to a type

And this is my parse method:

```
private void parse(ProjectInfo project, File resource) {
    final ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS11);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
    parser.setStatementsRecovery(true);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setCompilerOptions(project.getCompilerOptions());

    final Path sourcePath = Paths.get(resource.toURI());
    final char[] source = sourceToChar(sourcePath);
    if (source == null) {
        return;
    }
    parser.setSource(source);
    parser.setUnitName(resource.getName());

    final String[] sources = project.getProjectRelatedSources();
    final String[] classpaths = project.getProjectRelatedClasspaths();
    final String[] encoders = listOfEncoders(sources);

    parser.setEnvironment(classpaths, sources, encoders, true);
    // accept visitor(s)
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to show you my getCompilerOptions method:

```
private Map<String, String> getCompilerOptions(ProjectInfo project) {
    final Map<String, String> list = JavaCore.getOptions();
    list.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_SOURCE, JavaCore.VERSION_11);
    list.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_COMPLIANCE, JavaCore.VERSION_11);
    list.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_CODEGEN_TARGET_PLATFORM, JavaCore.ENABLED);
    list.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_DOC_COMMENT_SUPPORT, JavaCore.ENABLED);

    final Config config = new Config(project.getProjectPath() + File.separator + ".settings",
            "org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs");
    for (String key : config.keySet()) {
        list.put(key, config.value(key));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Config is just a handler for property file which I used to initialize the program. In this case, I read the property file org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs from the eclipse project and return it as a Map.

Everything is working and correctly detected on our IDE but somehow not on the standalone parser.
Can someone help me with it? Thank you in advice!

Best regards,
lftdbmr